# If $n$ is a factor of $m$, prove that $x^n-a^n$ is a factor of $x^m-a^m$

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics

I don't know how to prove this: If $n$ is a factor of $m$, prove that $x^n-a^n$ is a factor of $x^m-a^m$ ($n$,$m$ are positive integers).
 Help please.

Comment: Prove it first with $n=1$, and by induction on $m$.

Comment: Try with mathematical induction

Comment: You should convince yourself this is true for several $n$, $m$ first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have $m=nd$. Hence, we have
$$x^m-a^m = \left(x^n \right)^d - \left(a^n\right)^d$$
Now recall that $y-z$ is a factor of $y^d-z^d$. Hence, we have that $x^n-a^n$ to be a factor of $x^m-a^m$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $m=nc$ so you get $x^m = (x^n)^c$ and $a^m = (a^n)^c$. Set $y = x^n$ and $b = a^n$. You can restate this way: show that $y-b$ divides $y^c - b^c$. Now notice that $y^c - b^c = (y-b)(y^{c-1} + y^{c-2}b + \cdots + b^{c-1})$.