# Factor $a^{n} - b^{n}$ for complex numbers?

Tags: complex-analysis

For any $a, b \in \mathbb{C},$ show that $$a^{n}-b^{n} =(a-b) \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a^{k} b^{n-1-k}$$

Can you please show me how to prove it with easy arguments?

Comment: Multiply out the right hand side.

Comment: You can prove it by induction on $n.$

Comment: Specifically, $$a^{n+1}-b^{n+1}=a^{n+1}-a^nb + a^nb -b^{n+1}=(a-b)a^n + b(a^n-b^n)$$

Comment: So, for complex $a, b$ it's work?

Comment: Yes. It works in any commutative ring. It requires commutativity.

Comment: Why should it not work? Did you even try the hints pointed out by JP McCarthy and Thomas Andrews?

Comment: "It requires commutativity" ... and distribution, right.  And arguably associativity.  But in any event there's no reason that numbers being complex make any difference.

Comment: "Why should it not work?"  Do be fair other things *don't* work.  Very famously $\sqrt x \sqrt y \ne \sqrt {xy}$ (at least not superficially).  It's reasonable that someone may think this *might* not work in complex.  (But no reason to assume it *wouldn't* or to be surprised it does.)  [It works in both due to commutivity of addition and distribution of addition over multiplication-- it will hold true under *any* system that does.]

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1588027/if-n-is-a-factor-of-m-prove-that-xn-an-is-a-factor-of-xm-am)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall

$$a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}+\cdots a+1=\frac{a^n-1}{a-1},$$
or
$$(a-1)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}+\cdots a+1)=a^n-1,$$

which can be established inductively ?

Now, replacing $a$ by $\dfrac ab$, and multiplying by $b^n$,

$$(a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+\cdots ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1})=a^n-b^n.$$

Given the arithmetic operations involved, this works in any field, such as $\mathbb C_{+,\times}$.

Answer (score 1):

Associativity, Distribution, and commutivity work for multiplication and addition no matter what the elements are.  The proof in $\mathbb C \supset \mathbb R \supset \mathbb Q \supset \mathbb Z$ make no difference merely because some numbers are complex.

So  $(a-b) \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a^{k} b^{n-1-k}=$

$a\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a^{k} b^{n-1-k} - b\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a^{k} b^{n-1-k}=$

$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a^{k+ 1} b^{n-1-k}-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a^{k} b^{n-k}=$

$a^n + (\sum_{k=0}^{n-2} a^{k+1} b^{n-1-k}- \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} a^{k} b^{n-k}) - b^n=$

$a^n + (\sum_{k=0}^{n-2} a^{k+1} b^{n-1-k}-\sum_{k=0}^{n-2} a^{k+1} b^{n-1-k}) - b^n=$

$a^n - b^n$.

This proof works for $\mathbb C$ as well as it does for any set whose operations are distributive, commutative, and associative.

Comment: Yes, I thinking about problem with power in complex sense, but for natural power it's good defining operation.

Comment: "Yes, I thinking about problem with power in complex sense" I don't see why that makes any difference, "but for natural power it's good defining operation" I don't know what you mean by this.  What is your concern about complex numbers?  You still have $a^ba^c = a^{b+c}$